# Select list search on very large dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Currently I have Select2 in my application, and have previously implemented ajax calls to the database to get a smaller subset based on search query entered by a user.

However, users want to be able to click the back arrow on the browser, and have the query automatically run again (something that currently does not happen with Select2).  I was able to implement this by pulling the entire dataset (over 18,000 elements) in and calling select2 on that.

The problem with this is that Select2 basically does a foreach in a foreach when doing a search (foreach element in the dataset, go through each string and get the index of the query - which I understand is basically breaking the string into a char array and checking each char individually to see if the combination is found).  So every time someone types a character, we're looking at over 18,000 operations, even though the majority of elements are eliminated as options.

Is there a way to make Select2 actually eliminate the options that don't match (create and bind to a temp array or something like that) or perform a binary search instead of a linear search?  If not, are there any alternatives to Select2 that DO implement binary search instead of linear search, or would I need to create my own jQuery plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/8swnS/)<sup>**1**</sup> a hidden select element is used and a clone of that to filter input. The filtering is done with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < that.selector.options.length; i++) {
  if (re.test(that.selector.options[i].text)) {
   sclone.add(new Option(that.selector.options[i].text, i));
  }
}
```

Where `re` is a `RegExp` created from an input field that placed above the select clone.

Maybe that's an idea to play with?

<sup>**1**</sup> The language used in the first selector is dutch, but I suppose that shouldn't be obstructive to the idea.